# Which of the following logic statements are true

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

### Question

> $S_1: \,\,\forall x \,\exists y \, \forall z\,(x+y=z)$
>
> $S_2: \,\, \exists x \, \forall y \, \exists z\,(x+y=z)$

where $x,y, \text{and} \,\,z $ are real numbers.
Which of the following statements are true?

### My Approach

I think both $S_1$  and  $S_2$ are true.
Because  $S_1$ says for all $x$,there exists a $y$ whose sum will be $z$, a real number as sum of two real numbers are real.hence $S_1$ holds

same reasoning can be given for $S_2$ .but the answer says $S_2$ only.I know i am making some mistake ,don't know where.please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$S_1$ is false. Its negation is
$$\exists x\forall y\exists z\ x+y\ne z$$
and this is trivially true: take $x=0$, then for any $y$ take $z=y+1$.

$S_2$ is true, since given $x=0$ and some $y$ we can take $z=y$ to make the statement true.

Comment: Negation of $S_2$ is $\forall x \exists y \forall z (x+y \neq z)$  which should be false

if we take $y=0$, then for every $x$ ,$y$ ,$x=y$ 

Right?

Comment: @:parcly  i wrote negation of $S_2$ .for $S_2$ to be true ,its negation should be false ...right?

Comment: @laura OK, $\neg S_2$ _is_ false, since when $x=0$, there is no $y$ such that for all $z$ $x+y=z$ or $y=z$. Since $x=0$ fails the outer $\forall$, the whole negation is false.

Comment: thanks ..that is what u wa asking in my first comment...!

Answer (score 1):

> Because $S_1$ says for all $x$, there exists a $y$ whose sum will be $z$, a real number as sum of two real numbers are real.

No, $\forall x \,\exists y \, \forall z\,(x+y=z)$ sais that *for any* $x$, *there is* a $y$, such that *every* $z$ will equal their sum ($x+y$).

Whereas $\exists x \, \forall y \, \exists z\,(x+y=z)$ sais *there is* an $x$, such that *for every* $y$, *there is* a $z$ equal to their sum ($x+y$).

Comment: @:graham sir , thanks for your response. Using negation , i am able to understand it.but answering it straight away with your explanation is little confusing for me . $S_1$ says  for any $x,$ there is a  $y$, such that every $z$ will equal their sum $(x+y)$ here too for any $x$,if i take $y=0$, then sum $z$ is equal to $x+0=x$. why it is false ? please help me out!

Comment: *Every* $z$, not just *some* $z$.  All of them.  Take any $x$ and some $y$, can $x+y$ equal every $z$?  @laura

Comment: yes ..i got it ..thanks a lot!